# Error Hosting a WCF Service in IIS 6.0

Tags: wcf, web-services, iis-6

I've currently got a service that I created on my machine and it worked fine locally, but when deployed to our Windows 2003 server using IIS 6.0 I get the exception:

> The HTTP request is unauthorized with
>   client authentication scheme
>   'Anonymous'.  The authentication
>   header received from the server was
>   'Negotiate,NTLM'.

A quick google on the error leads one to believe that this is easy to fix, but none of the fixes have worked for me so far.

Here's what I have in my service's Web.config:

```
<services>
   <service name="WcfService2.Service1" 
            behaviorConfiguration="WcfService2.Service1Behavior">
     <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" 
               bindingName="basicBindingConfig" 
               contract="WcfService2.IService1"/>
   </service>
 </services>

 <bindings>
   <basicHttpBinding>
     <binding name="basicBindingConfig">
       <security mode="TransportCredentialOnly">
         <transport clientCredentialType="Ntlm"/>
       </security>
     </binding>
   </basicHttpBinding>
 </bindings>

<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="WcfService2.Service1Behavior">
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
```

My test client has an App.config with this:

```
<bindings>
  <basicHttpBinding>
    <binding name="basicBindingConfig_IService1">
      <security mode="None">
        <transport clientCredentialType="Ntlm" 
             proxyCredentialType="None" realm="" />
      </security>
    </binding>
  </basicHttpBinding>
</bindings>
```

And my test client access call is:

```
Dim client As New ServiceReference1.Service1Client()

client.GetData()
```

Any idea what's wrong here?  I've tried changing the Ntlm type to Windows and to None, neither of which worked.  I can navigate to it in the browser and it looks fine, but when I actually start trying to use it I get the above error.

Comment: What is the Security setting on your virtual directory in IIS?

Comment: I have anonymous access enabled and I have integrated Windows authentication checked

Comment: Have you tried disabling anonymous access at the virtual directory

Comment: Yeah, that doesn't change the error at all, but it does make accessing it through the browser throw an error.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm so you tried transportClientCredential = Windows and it still doesn't work eh, take a look at:

From  http://support.microsoft.com/kb/215383

IIS 6.0

1. Click Start, click Run, type cmd, and then press ENTER.
2. Locate the directory that contains the Adsutil.vbs file. By default, this directory is C:\Inetpub\Adminscripts.
3. Use the following command to retrieve the current values for the NTAuthenticationProviders metabase property:
     cscript adsutil.vbs get w3svc/WebSite/root/NTAuthenticationProviders
     In this command, WebSite is a placeholder for the Web site ID number. The Web site ID number of the default Web site is 1.

   Warning Do not perform a copy-and-paste operation to paste the command from this article. This operation may cause issues with the property setting. To avoid these issues, type the whole command at a command prompt.

   Note This command fails if the NTAuthenticationProviders metabase property is not defined. For more information, see the note earlier in this section.

   If the Negotiate process is enabled, this command returns the following information:
     NTAuthenticationProviders : (STRING) "Negotiate,NTLM"
4. If the command in step 3 does not return the string "Negotiate,NTLM," use the following command to enable the Negotiate process:
     cscript adsutil.vbs set w3svc/WebSite/root/NTAuthenticationProviders "Negotiate,NTLM"
5. Repeat step 3 to verify that the Negotiate process has been enabled.

Note If you receive an error when you try to verify that the Negotiate process has been enabled, make sure that you did not leave a space between "Negotiate" and "NTLM." For example, "Negotiate,NTLM" differs from "Negotiate, NTLM."